# "No such file or directory" error when trying to execute a binary

Tags: linux, assembly, ubuntu-14.04, nasm, x86-64

I'm using the NASM assembler on Ubuntu. I'm trying to execute this code:

```
section .data

fmt db "%d",0
val1 dd 23
val2 dd 9
val3 dd 7

section .text
global _start
extern printf

_start:
push val1
push val2
push val3

pop rax 
pop rbx 
imul rax, rbx
push rax 

pop rax 
pop rbx 
add rax, rbx
push rax

pop rax 
mov [val1], rax

push val1
push fmt
call printf
add rsp, 16

mov rax,0   
ret
```

`nasm -f elf64 test64.asm` successfully creates test64.o and `ld -s -o hello test64.o -lc` creates an executable file, but when I try to run it, I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Regarding the edit - I'm adding Linux tag back in. This code, is compiled with NASM; is about running executables in a Linux like environment (confirmed with the fact we are tagged as Ubuntu); and the linker target is ELF64. I would suggest that given that information, that Linux is still an applicable tag because it is a question about software development in a Linux environment, and to fix the issue will require a Linux specific solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You're using the wrong calling convention for `printf`. The arguments were passed in registers, not on the stack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI. Also, `printf` needs a value in `EAX` (0 in your case).

2) When the program starts, there is no return address on the stack. Look here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters. Therefor,

```
mov rax,0   
ret
```

is wrong. But if you use the [64-bit-Linux-syscall](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64)

```
mov edi, 0                  ; return 0 (success)
mov eax, 60                 ; sys_exit
syscall
```

you will not see the output of `printf`, because it is buffered and the buffer won't be flushed. You can call `fflush(0)` or `exit`.

3) To use C functions in Linux you have to link with a special loader (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`). I just don't know if it is installed by default.

4) `push val1` pushes the **address** of val1, not its value. Use brackets to get the values. I guess you wanted just load a 32-bit DWORD into a 64-bit register. You can directly load the DWORD into a 32-bit register (the upper part of the 64-bit-register will be cleared) or use `movsx` for a signed operation.

Quintessence:

```
section .data

fmt db `%d\n`,0             ; backticks for '\n'
val1 dd 23
val2 dd 9
val3 dd 7

section .text
global _start
extern printf, exit

_start:

movsx rax, dword [val1]     ; signed dword to signed qword
movsx rbx, dword [val2]
imul rax, rbx

mov ebx, [val3]             ; unsigned dword into RBX
add rax, rbx
mov [val1], rax

mov rdi, fmt                ; string pointer
mov rsi, [val1]             ; immediate value
xor eax, eax                ; no vector registers used
call printf

xor edi, edi
call exit
```

> nasm -f elf64 test64.asm 
>     ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test64 test64.o -lc 
>     ./test64

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!

Comment: @TatianaRoodenko: you could also just use 32bit ops in 64bit code, instead of sign-extending to 64.  Each instruction will be one byte shorter (no REX prefix).  `mov esi, [val1]` / `imul esi, [val2]` / `add esi, [val3]`.  Since you're going to call printf eventually, you might as well build your input in `rsi` in the first place, instead of moving it there (esp. not through memory, unless you want to save the value for later).  Also note that `mov [val1], rax`  overwrites val1 and val2, because it's a 64bit store.

Comment: @PeterCordes  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try to start it with?

   ```
   ./test
   ```

It might be, that the current path is not in the list of paths, where to search for executables.

2. Check that the permissions allow the execution of the file, e.g.:

   ```
   $ ls ./test

   -rwxr-xr-x user user .... test
   ```

Comment: Yes, I did, it doesn't work. Also tried to run it with sudo, but got the same error

Comment: How does the file look like using `ls`?

Comment: `-rwxrwxr-x 1 cephalgia cephalgia 2072 гру 12 18:37 ./test64*`

Comment: Yes, I always tried this